I am trying to package a simple python file into a c file with cython but it keeps having an error
the error is
#include "Python.h"
#ifndef Py_PYTHON_H

**#error Python headers needed to compile C extensions, please install development version of Python.**


#elif PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x02070000 || (0x03000000 <= PY_VERSION_HEX && PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x03030000)

**#error Cython requires Python 2.7+ or Python 3.3+.**


i was trying to turn a python file with one line of code into a c file with cython
